# How do I find the length (or dimensions, size) of a numpy matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

For a numpy matrix in python

```
from numpy import matrix
A = matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

How can I find the length of a row (or column) of this matrix? Equivalently, how can I know the number of rows or columns?

So far, the only solution I've found is:

```
len(A)
len(A[:,1])
len(A[1,:])
```

Which returns 2, 2, and 1, respectively. From this I've gathered that `len()` will return the number of rows, so I can always us the transpose, `len(A.T)`, for the number of columns. However, this feels unsatisfying and arbitrary, as when reading the line `len(A)`, it isn't immediately obvious that this should return the number of rows. It actually works differently than `len([1,2])` would for a 2D python array, as this would return 2.

So, is there a more intuitive way to find the size of a matrix, or is this the best I have?

Comment: First result for numpy dimensions btw, try the search box ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question! I did try searching, but "numpy matrix dimensions" (or length or size for that matter) didn't result in anything useful. I read numpy tutorials, but shape was covered in the ndarray section, and I didn't make the connection that properties of ndarray's would be extended to matrices. I attempted to solve my problem by switching to numpy arrays, but these didn't have the linear algebra properties of matrices, furthering my belief that they didn't share properties

Answer (score 282, accepted):

`shape` is a property of both numpy ndarray's and matrices.

```
A.shape
```

will return a tuple (m, n), where m is the number of rows, and n is the number of columns.

In fact, the numpy `matrix` object is built on top of the `ndarray` object, one of numpy's two fundamental objects (along with a universal function object), so it inherits from `ndarray`

Answer (score 42):

`matrix.size` according to [the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#array-methods) returns the `Number of elements in the array.` Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the number of rows or columns, not the total number of elements

Comment: Quick note: matrix.size is an 'int' object and cannot be called!